# How to make hamburger menu show/hide in simple grid/flex based menu?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I just made a simple grid/flex based menu. What can I do to make the hamburger menu working i.e. to show/hide menu on click? Is it possible to do this without using JavaScript?

The code I have right now looks as follows:

```css
.menu {
    display: grid;
    grid-template: auto / auto 3cm 3cm 3cm 3cm 3cm auto;
    background: #444;
}

.menu-item {
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
}

.menu-item:hover {
    background: #fff6;
}

.burger {
    display: none;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #444;
    color: #fff;
}

.burger > div {
    text-align: center;
}

@media (max-width: 20cm) and (orientation: portrait) {
    .menu {
        max-width: 8cm;
        grid-template: 0 auto auto auto auto auto 0 / auto;
    }
    .burger {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="burger">
  <div>BURG</div>
  <div>Company Name</div>
</div>
<div class="menu">
  <div></div>
  <div class="menu-item">Home</div>
  <div class="menu-item">Products</div>
  <div class="menu-item">Manuals</div>
  <div class="menu-item">Customers</div>
  <div class="menu-item">Contact</div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You could do it without javascript, but why would you want to?  In order to do it without javascript you would be going back to the server to set an html attribute, then reloading a partial (or possibly a whole) view.  Don't fear the javascript mate.

Comment: why would you be going back to the server? if it's all in CSS, it's already been loaded, so no trip back to the server. try Kevin Powell's tutorial on YouTube (Responsive nav with Flexbox and Grid and no JS): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8QKOaTYvYUA&t=1952s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a really simple example with your code and with jQuery slideToggle() function. Hope that helps you get an idea. This can be improved a lot. (Reduce screen width to see hamburger pop up in jsfiddle)

```js
var _burger = $('.burger');
var _menu = $('.menu');

_burger.on('click', function() {
  console.log("burger clicked");
  _menu.slideToggle();
});
```

```css
.menu {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: auto / auto 3cm 3cm 3cm 3cm 3cm auto;
  background: #444;
}

.menu-item {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}

.menu-item:hover {
  background: #fff6;
}

.menu.hide {
  display: none;
}

.burger {
  display: none;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #444;
  color: #fff;
}

.burger>div {
  text-align: center;
}

@media (max-width: 20cm) and (orientation: portrait) {
  .menu {
    max-width: 8cm;
    grid-template: 0 auto auto auto auto auto 0 / auto;
  }
  .burger {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="burger">
  <div>BURG</div>
  <div>Company Name</div>
</div>
<div class="menu">
  <div></div>
  <div class="menu-item">Home</div>
  <div class="menu-item">Products</div>
  <div class="menu-item">Manuals</div>
  <div class="menu-item">Customers</div>
  <div class="menu-item">Contact</div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I was full of hope that there is a way to do this without JavaScript, but your code does what it should does and I like this solution. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I can do it with minimal javascript. By default you want your burger menu to show on screen (`position:absolute;left:0;top:0;`) from burger class and (  `transform: translate(0, 0);`) from open class. Then you want to translate the div off screen (    `transform: translate(-300px, 0);`). By moving it 300px to the left it essentially  moves the burger menu off screen.

```
.burger {
    height:100%;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #444;
    color: #fff;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
}

.open {
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}

.close {
    transform: translate(-300px, 0);
    transition: transform 0.3s ease;
}

function hideMenu() {
  var burgMenu = window.document.getElementById("burg-menu");
  burgMenu.classList.toggle("open");
  burgMenu.classList.toggle("close");
}
```

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jchaplin2/d5zyoL8o/9/)